# Joint distribution of number of trials needed to get 1 and 2 heads

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, bivariate-distributions

I have the following random variables

$X = $ number of trials needed to obtain the first head

$Y = $ number of trials needed to get two heads

in repeated tosses of a fair coin. How I cand find the joint distribution of $X,Y$?
I think that $X$ is a geometric, and $Y$ a negative binomial, because do we want the second success in a certain number of trials, although this would also be a possible geometric? I had thought that the joint is
$$
p_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2^x} \binom{y-1}{2-1} \frac{1}{2^{2}} \frac{1}{2^{y-2}}, \quad x = 1,2,...; y = x+1,x+2,...
$$
but $\displaystyle \sum_{x =1} \sum_{ y = x+1} p_{X,Y}(x,y) \neq 1$. Somebody could help me? greetings.

Comment: Are the two heads (for $Y$) required to be consecutive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that $X$ is a geometric, and $Y$ a negative binomial, because do we want the second success in a certain number of trials, although this would also be a possible geometric?

Yes.  Those are the marginal distributions for these random variables. $${p_{\small X}(x)=2^{-x}\mathbf 1_{x\in[[1..\infty)]}\\[2ex]p_{\small Y}(y)=\binom{y-1}{1}2^{-y}\mathbf 1_{y\in[[2..\infty)]}}$$

However, the joint pmf is *not* simply the product of these marginals, as the random variables are *not independent* (the first head thrown must be less than the second head, which is a dependency.)

However, notice that if the first head occurs after $X$ trials then the second head will occur after $Y-X$ *subsequent* trials.  So the conditional distribution of $Y-X$ for a given $X$ **is geometric**. Leading to:

$$p_{\small Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = 2^{-(y-x)}\,\mathbf 1_{(x,y)\in\Bbb Z^2:1\leq x\lt y}$$

And so...

Answer (score 2):

To get any particular $x,y$ values, you must get the first head on flip $x$ and the second head on flip $y$, with all other flips up to the $y$th flip being tails. Since this requires one specific sequence of $y$ flips, the probability of $P_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is given by:

$$P_{X,Y}(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{1}{2^y} & {\rm for }
\;\; y\ge 2, \;\; 1\le x \le y-1 \\ 0 &\rm{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$